# Wordpress - Listing of categories not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an interesting one. I have a WP site that I need to grab a list of categories for to build a menu from. I've been looking around and it looks like I'm using the most agreed upon working code, and locally, it works just fine. However, once I upload it to my hosting server (MediaTemple), I find that it is NOT generating the list as I expect. I have the two sites (locally, MT) set up nearly identical, the only difference is the site on MT has MORE categories.

Here's what I have:

```
    <?php 
    $args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
      );
    $categories=get_categories($args);
    ?>
```

and then further down:

```
            <ul id="categorySubmenu">
                <?php
                foreach($categories as $cat) {
                ?>
                    <li><?php echo "<a href='" . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . "'> $cat->cat_name </a>"  ?></li>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
```

In the local site, I'm getting a list in the  of all the categories I have in WP (just 2 locally), however, in the hosted site, I get nothing returned there (nothing listed, just an empty `<ul></ul>`)

Seems like pretty basic stuff. Is there something I'm missing?!?!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: "it is NOT generating the list as I expect" How do you expect it to be generated?

Comment: Oops...hit submit before I finished :) Updating now...

Comment: Have you tried using [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories)? Looks like it should do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Same deal...works locally, but once I upload the page, it has no categories. The only difference, with wp_list_categories, I get "no categories" listed in the menu. I guess it must be a configuration problem then....not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nevermind...found my typo. This works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change:

```
get_category_link($cat->term_id)
```

To:

```
get_category_link($cat->cat_ID)
```

Or you can simply use:

```
wp_list_categories();
```